# Excel - Remove character from end of string

Tags: excel

I have some data in excel, from which I want to remove underscore (_) from end of the string. Is it possible to do it? If so, please help.
For example:

```
AA_BB_CC_
AA_BB_CC_DD
AA_BB_
```

From the first and third line, I want to remove the '_' from end of the string only. But no changes to be made to second line.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @MK7, can u explain this first line second line text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is there in the Column A, use the function:
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1).
It will read all the characters excluding the last one.

Comment: This is not what the OP wanted...he did not want the 2nd one to be modified, but this formula will strip the last character regardless. Not sure why this was marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="_",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

If your data begins in A1 then enter in B1 and fill down.